# How do I go about implementing the following layout in a custom UITableViewCell of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

This is what I want to show in my custom UITableViewCell. The two UILabels and the UIImageView are being populated dynamically from the server. Both the UILabels can have more than two lines of text that mean the height of the labels will also be decided dynamically. Also, the images coming in the UIImageView are of different aspect ratios and hence their sizes will vary as well (I want to keep aspect ratio of the images, and that's why I'm using contentMode of aspectFit).

[image]

I'm new to iOS application development and tried implementing it myself and got the following result:

As the images shows there is a large space between the top UILabel and the UIImageView. Similarly, there's also a large space between the bottom UILabel and the UIImageView.

[image]

However, this is not the intended behaviour of my app. 
I searched more on the internet and found one solution regarding this 'space problem'.

```
**

internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != nil {
                detailSubImage.removeConstraint(oldValue!) 
            }
            if aspectConstraint != nil {
                detailSubImage.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        aspectConstraint = nil
    }

    func setPostedImage(image : UIImage) {
        let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height
        aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailSubImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: detailSubImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)
        detailSubImage.image = image
    }

}

 **
```

I call the setPostedImage() method on the image I want to assign on the UIImageView before setting the image. This method() removes the constraints at run time which remove the white spacing between the labels and the image.(cannot show an example as I'm not allowed to post more than two pictures)

After using this method, at first, I thought I solved the problem but then the console of Xcode threw too many warnings regarding the unsatisfying constraints which again is a problem.

Comment: Did you tried setting constrain in storyboard?

Comment: upload your storyboard file i will fix it.. if you can you can upload your project

Comment: Yes I've to both the UILabels and the UIImageView (leading-trailing-top-bottom)

Comment: I'm not allowed to post more than two pictures. Can you give me your email ID?